# Script loads in Editor, but not with SceneManager.LoadScene()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game with a main menu, and a main scene.
If I load the scene through the editor, and click play everything works fine.
However if I load my main menu scene through the editor, then load the 2nd scene through that the script doesn't load. None of my scripts load.
I'm using private void Start() and private void Update()
I tried changing them both to public as-well and it still didn't work.
I tried calling the function upon Awake() as-well with no luck.
My question is; Is there a common reason for this to occur? Why are they loading fine through the editor but not when the scene is loaded through the game itself?

List of camera scripts
[image: Camera Script]

This is the game scene, this is how it always looks. My camera, and player scripts fail to load. Animation fails to play as-well.
[image: Game Scene, player and camera both fail to activate scripts.]

Main camera scripts
[image: Main Character scripts]

Coin scripts that fail to load.
[image: Coin scripts]

Comment: It might help if you posted some code/screenshots. It could be as simple as the gameobject you expect to exist doesn't for that 2nd scene. Without more info its hard to tell.

Comment: do you have the second scene in build settings?

Comment: @UmairM Yes, It's in my build settings. The scene itself loads, only the scripts fail to load.

Comment: @code11 Screenshots added